# Why do I get a parse error when I decompile?

Tags: python, uncompyle6

I have a few questions.

1. I used pyinstxtractor.py with no issue. No problem at all about this; but I wanted to know why does it say Python version is 0 for this specific EXE but others may differ like an actual version? Does 0 mean obfuscated or etc?
2. (Actual problem) Why do I get this parse error?

So I have my exe and it decompiles maybe 1/4 of my script. Then I get a error saying parse error, then most of the rest of the code looks like:

Uncompyle6 error from cmd prompt:

```
    Instruction context:

 L. 131       120  POP_BLOCK
                 122  LOAD_CONST               (False, '', '', '')
->               124  RETURN_VALUE
                 126  POP_BLOCK
                 128  JUMP_FORWARD        170  'to 170'
               130_0  COME_FROM_FINALLY     8  '8'
Instruction context:

 L. 140        36  POP_EXCEPT
->                38  LOAD_CONST               (False, '', '', '')
                  40  RETURN_VALUE
                  42  END_FINALLY
                44_0  COME_FROM            14  '14'


# file main.pyc
# Deparsing stopped due to parse error
main.pyc --
# decompile failed
```

Why does this happen?